# JSSOR Error in console

Tags: jquery, slider

I want to implement a jssor nested-slider.

The Slider is shown, but it doesen't autoplay until I slide the first manually. Then it starts in the normal autoplay mode.

Also I get an error in the chrome console:

Uncaught Error: Option '$ArrowNavigatorOptions' spepcified, but UI 'arrowleft' not defined. Define 'arrowleft' to enable direct navigation, or remove option '$ArrowNavigatorOptions' to disable direct navigation.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: were you able to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in 'examples-jquery' folder.
see [nested slider](http://www.jssor.com/examples-jquery/nested-slider.source.html) demo